# How to check PayPal expired subscription

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I'm developing website, where user will have some paid content. In this case I'm using PayPal subscription. I successfully made subscription and want to get subscription expiration date. I'm using `GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails` method to get information about subscription. Here is result of this method:

```
`array (size=45)
  'PROFILEID' => string 'I-DLUN4G0R3G0F' (length=14)
  'STATUS' => string 'Active' (length=6)
  'AUTOBILLOUTAMT' => string 'NoAutoBill' (length=10)
  'DESC' => string 'Monthly subscription' (length=20)
  'MAXFAILEDPAYMENTS' => string '3' (length=1)
  'SUBSCRIBERNAME' => string 'blah-blah-blah' (length=14)
  'PROFILESTARTDATE' => string '2015-09-08T07:00:00Z' (length=20)
  'NEXTBILLINGDATE' => string '2015-09-08T10:00:00Z' (length=20)
  'NUMCYCLESCOMPLETED' => string '0' (length=1)
  'NUMCYCLESREMAINING' => string '0' (length=1)
  'OUTSTANDINGBALANCE' => string '0.00' (length=4)
  'FAILEDPAYMENTCOUNT' => string '0' (length=1)
  'TRIALAMTPAID' => string '0.00' (length=4)
  'REGULARAMTPAID' => string '0.00' (length=4)
  'AGGREGATEAMT' => string '0.00' (length=4)
  'AGGREGATEOPTIONALAMT' => string '0.00' (length=4)
  'FINALPAYMENTDUEDATE' => string '1970-01-01T00:00:00Z' (length=20)
  'TIMESTAMP' => string '2015-09-08T10:55:59Z' (length=20)
  'CORRELATIONID' => string 'fb5da7dc8451f' (length=13)
  'ACK' => string 'Success' (length=7)
  'VERSION' => string '86.0' (length=4)
  'BUILD' => string '17972692' (length=8)
  'BILLINGPERIOD' => string 'Month' (length=5)
  'BILLINGFREQUENCY' => string '1' (length=1)
  'TOTALBILLINGCYCLES' => string '0' (length=1)
  'CURRENCYCODE' => string 'GBP' (length=3)
  'AMT' => string '9.99' (length=4)
  'SHIPPINGAMT' => string '0.00' (length=4)
  'TAXAMT' => string '0.00' (length=4)
  'REGULARBILLINGPERIOD' => string 'Month' (length=5)
  'REGULARBILLINGFREQUENCY' => string '1' (length=1)
  'REGULARTOTALBILLINGCYCLES' => string '0' (length=1)
  'REGULARCURRENCYCODE' => string 'GBP' (length=3)
  'REGULARAMT' => string '9.99' (length=4)
  'REGULARSHIPPINGAMT' => string '0.00' (length=4)
  'REGULARTAXAMT' => string '0.00' (length=4)
`
```

As you can see above, I have `NEXTBILLINGDATE` field, and I thought that it's what I needed. The problem is that this field shows incorrect time. Seems like `NEXTBILLIGDATE` should be something like 2015-10-08T07:00:00Z according to my `REGULARBILLINGPERIOD` and `REGULARBILLINGFREQUENCY` fields. Also, maybe someone know how to test expired subscription? Or how to make expired subscription, is there any tools in PayPal sandbox?. Hope to find solution here. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The first charge happens within 24 hours after the profile created according to the doc, so if you call GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails before the first charge(for example right after the create call success) the NEXTBILLINGDATE will still be the start date. 
There's no tool or API to make expired subscription in sandbox, you can create a daily subscription and set TOTALBILLINGCYCLES=1, and the next day it will just expire..